# The solvability of a system

Tags: real-analysis

Let

$3x+2y+z^{2}+u+v^{2}=0$,

$4x+3y+z+u^{2}+v+w+2=0$,

$x+z+w+u^{2}+2=0$.

Discuss the solvability of the system for u,v and w in terms of x,y and z near ($0,0,0,0,0,-2$)

In which conditions the system will be inconsistant?

I found det($F_{U}$($X_{0}$,$U_{0}$))=$0$ . Is this useful?

Comment: You can write your expressions with just the $\$$'s enclosing the entire expression rather than around each variable, it's shorter and looks neater (imo).

Comment: I just learned it, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Computing $S$-polynomials (or performing elementary computations) we obtain a unique solution of $u,v,w$ in terms of $x,y,z$:
\begin{align*}
v & = -(3x+3y),\\
u & = -(9x^2 + 18xy + 3x + 9y^2 + 2y + z^2),\\
w & = -(81x^4+\cdots +z^4+z+2).
\end{align*}

Comment: Can we solve this by using the matrix system?

Comment: I am not sure which matrix system you mean, but if you subtract your third equation form the second you have already $v+3x+3y=0$.